# Running Django app with docker-compose - applying migrations causes db to stop responding to queries but no errors are raised

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, migration

I searched for this, and it seems like every post has some sort of related error message, but I get *no* error messages for this problem. It took me a while to even realize what was going on, but I still don't understand *why*.

Essentially, I am trying to containerize my Django app with Docker. I am able to interact with the app on `localhost:8000`, and if I try my app's search function (the only functionality I've built out so far) before I apply migrations, I get an error as expected because certain tables don't exist. I can see in the logs the database is trying to search for the input from the web app.

Once I apply migrations with `docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate --noinput`, and I search for any term, I get **no results back at all and no errors**, and there's nothing in the database logs to suggest it's handling the query. I do see in the logs for the web container that it's noticing I am typing in search terms and pressing enter. On the frontend, I just see "0 results for [search term]", which is what should be returned if the db can't find any matches.

First, here's my `docker-compose` file.

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./src/web_app
    command: python manage.py migrate
    command: python manage.py makemigrations
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./src/web_app/:/usr/src/web_app/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

After I apply migrations with `docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate --noinput`, I do see that the tables exist, but there's a lack of communication between the search queries I submit on the website and the database processing them, and I am not sure why? It was working locally just fine.

[image]

Here are the models and views for the search function:

```py
# models

class SearchManager(models.Manager):
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(text__icontains=query)
        return qs

class Tlk(models.Model):
    str_id = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.CharField(
        max_length=3000
    )  

    objects = SearchManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

```py
# views.py

class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = "dac/test.html"
    count = 0

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["count"] = self.count or 0
        context["query"] = self.request.GET.get("q")
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        query = request.GET.get("q", None)

        if query is not None:
            dao_results = DAO_TLK.objects.search(query)
            da2_results = DA2_TLK.objects.search(query)
            dai_results = DAI_TLK.objects.search(query)

            queryset_chain = chain(dao_results, da2_results, dai_results)

            qs = list(queryset_chain)
            self.count = len(qs)
            return qs
        return DAO_TLK.objects.none()
```

---

**Edit 01/31/2021**: I tried to create an entrypoint file to apply migrations on start up, but still I don't see the same behavior on my dockerized app as I do locally.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# wait for Postgres to start
function postgres_ready(){
python << END
import sys
import psycopg2
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=$DB_NAME, user=$DB_USER, password=$DB_PASSWORD, host=$DB_HOST)
except psycopg2.OperationalError:
    sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(0)
END
}

until postgres_ready; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

echo "Applying migrations..."
python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

When I put text into the search box and press enter, I should see a list of results on my app. I also think I should see the db running the query in the docker logs, right? I don't see that happening, but I do see the web app container logging the `GET` request.

Logs from intial start up to testing the search functionality

```
db_1   |
db_1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1   |
db_1   | 2021-02-01 00:14:07.964 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.2.0) 9.2.0,
 64-bit
db_1   | 2021-02-01 00:14:07.964 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2021-02-01 00:14:07.964 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2021-02-01 00:14:07.968 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2021-02-01 00:14:07.982 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-02-01 00:12:49 UTC
db_1   | 2021-02-01 00:14:07.987 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | Applying migrations...
web_1  | Operations to perform:
web_1  |   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, dac, sessions
web_1  | Running migrations:
web_1  |   No migrations to apply.
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  |
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | February 01, 2021 - 00:14:11
web_1  | Django version 3.1.2, using settings 'web_app.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
web_1  | [01/Feb/2021 00:26:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3231
web_1  | [01/Feb/2021 00:26:28] "GET /test-search/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4173
web_1  | [01/Feb/2021 00:26:33] "GET /test-search/?q=hello HTTP/1.1" 200 4174
```

Why don't I see the db running a query in the logs?

Comment: Why exactly you would get results back, did you add entries to *new tables^  ?

Comment: For reference, I added the model and view. Essentially a text search function. This is where my shallow knowledge of django might be the issue.

Locally, I imported my data into the database from a json file. If I look with pgAdmin at my database, the data is there/when I do things locally via the shell I see there's entries in the tables. I am not sure how that translates to docker

Comment: it does not translate to docker, as you have  different database in docker container which you did define. So basically after migrations you have only an empty database

Comment: @iklinac -- ah, that could be it. So, when people containerize their django projects, how do they import their data? Would be nice to just run `docker-compose up -d --build` and navigate to localhost to test changes in an environment that matches prod.

Comment: You would after you migrate database first time as you have set volume https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ you can run also run commands on your docker containers with https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/

Comment: @iklinac maybe i've misunderstood you, but even after applying migrations my app doesn't behave the same way it does locally/I think the db is empty. If I created an app to host blog posts, it would be like I don't see any posts. Is that normal with docker? If so, what is the point of containerizing an app if I need to  go through the process of adding data to the db after spinning up the container? I actually never see that addressed in tutorials, which is why I think the data should be there after applying migrations.

Comment: I also added an entry point that automatically applies the migrations -- added this + logs when I try out the search function in the dockerized app as an edit to my post above

Comment: No, data is not automatically being migrated. If data should exist consider data migrations / fixtures https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/writing-migrations/